# Cassandra query just return 5000 rows

Tags: python, cassandra

I use this code to query data from cassandra, but the result is only 5000 rows, but in fact there are 120,000 rows in the database table, how can I query all the data?

```
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
import pandas as pd

cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['192.168.2.4'],port=9042)
session = cluster.connect()

def testContectRemoteDatabase():
    contact_points = ['192.168.2.4']
    auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='XXX', password='XX')
    cluster = Cluster(contact_points=contact_points, auth_provider=auth_provider)
    session = cluster.connect()
    cql_str = 'select * from DB1.mytable ;'
    simple_statement = SimpleStatement(cql_str, consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
    execute_result = session.execute(simple_statement, timeout=None)
    result = execute_result._current_rows
    cluster.shutdown()
    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    df.to_csv('./my_test.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testContectRemoteDatabase()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [by design](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.21/query_paging/):

> By default, `Session.default_fetch_size` controls how many rows will be fetched per page. This can be overridden per-query by setting `fetch_size` on a `Statement`. By default, each page will contain at most 5000 rows.

Setting this to `None` will disable automatic paging:

```
simple_statement = SimpleStatement(
    cql_str, consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE, fetch_size=None)
```

Comment: This is very helpful.Thanks!

Comment: @CR7 I need to point out that doing a full table scan isn't a good idea. Cassandra is designed for OLTP workloads. You code *might* work if you have a single node and a small number of partitions but it won't scale. You should use Spark for analytics queries. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez is right. I assumed that 120K records is not a big deal but depending on the use case it can be.

Comment: I just realised you posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040650/ and ran into the exact issue I mentioned above. I've posted a more complete answer there too. Cheers!