# cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: 'Unable to complete the operation against any hosts' when querying a lot of data

Tags: python, cassandra

I use this code to query data from cassandra:

```
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
import pandas as pd

cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['192.168.2.4'],port=9042)
session = cluster.connect()

def testContectRemoteDatabase():
    contact_points = ['192.168.2.4']
    auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='XXX', password='XX')
    cluster = Cluster(contact_points=contact_points, auth_provider=auth_provider)
    session = cluster.connect()
    cql_str = 'select * from DB1.mytable ;'
    simple_statement = SimpleStatement(cql_str, consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE,fetch_size=2000000)
    execute_result = session.execute(simple_statement, timeout=None)
    result = execute_result._current_rows
    cluster.shutdown()
    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    df.to_csv('./my_test.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testContectRemoteDatabase()
```

When I set `fetch_size=1000000`, there is no error, but when I set `fetch_size=2000000`, this error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    testContectRemoteDatabase()
  File "test.py", line 17, in testContectRemoteDatabase
    execute_result = session.execute(simple_statement, timeout=None)
  File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 2618, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
  File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 4877, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {<Host: 192.168.2.4:9042 datacenter1>: ConnectionShutdown('errors=Connection heartbeat timeout after 30 seconds, last_host=192.168.2.4:9042')})
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

An unbounded `SELECT` where you're doing a full table scan doesn't work. Cassandra is designed for OLTP workloads.

Your query is very expensive and puts pressure on a single coordinator to retrieve all partitions from all nodes in the cluster. This *might* work for single-node clusters with a small number of partitions. But by this point, you would've worked out that your code won't scale.

When you have dozens of nodes and millions of partitions distributed around the ring, the single coordinator node won't be able to cope and the replicas won't be able to respond within the timeout.

I recommend that you use Spark for analytics queries. The Spark connector for Cassandra optimises analytics queries and is able to handle them better. It also scales. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't very optimal from Cassandra point of view as described by Erick, plus it won't work when you have more data than you have available memory.

If you just need to export data from DB to CSV or other formats - don't reinvent the wheel, but use [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html).  it's will be as simple as:

```
dsbulk unload -k keyspace -t table -u user -p password -url filename
```

See following blog posts for examples:

- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations